# Function that takes parent as an argument call with child object: what is the reason of copying twice?

Tags: c++, function, copy-constructor

Having the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int x;
    A(){}
    ~A(){std::cout <<"~A("<<x<<")\n";}
};
struct B: public A
{
};
void f(A a)
{
    a.x = 2;
}

void main()
{
    B b;
    std::cout <<"----------\n";
    b.x = 1;
    f(b);
    b.x = 3;
    std::cout <<"----------\n";
}
```

In this case the output is following:

```
----------
~A(2)
~A(1)
----------
~A(3)
```

The same code but virtual function is added to parent class:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int x;
    A(){}
    ~A(){std::cout <<"~A("<<x<<")\n";}
    virtual void ff() {}
    A(A& ca): x(ca.x){}
};
struct B: public A
{
};
void f(A a)
{
    a.x = 2;
}

void main()
{
    B b;
    std::cout <<"----------\n";
    b.x = 1;
    f(b);
    b.x = 3;
    std::cout <<"----------\n";
}
```

In this case we have the following output:

```
----------
~A(2)
----------
~A(3)
```

**EDIT:**
**Compiler is: MSVCPP 10**

---

The questions are the following:

1. Why we have double copying in the first case?
2. Why we have only one copying in the second case?
3. The 1st case: why does compiler not optimizes the 1st case (by reducing copy operations quantity)?
4. Does the following code:

   ```
   void f(int);
   //...
   double d;
   f(d);
   ```

also make double-copying?

Comment: Note in addition to the `virtual` function, `A(A& ca): x(ca.x){}` has also been added in the second example.

Comment: It would help you to understand it better if you added `cout` statements to the DTOR of B and the CTORs of both. Print the addresses as well for extra info and insight. :)

Comment: What is your compiler? Do you compile with optimizations enabled?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Exactly my Q.The output posted in the Q seems rather strange to me.I don't see where the extra copy in the first example is needed at all.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Als I've edited the initial post. My compiler is MSVC++ 10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output on gcc 4.3.4 for both cases is:

```
----------
~A(2)
----------
~B
~A(3)
```

**[Example 1](http://ideone.com/BtSR1)**
**[Example 2](http://ideone.com/Itj6T)**

This output can be explained as:
When you call `f(b);` an copy of the object of type `B` is created since it is pass by value.
But there is Object slicing, since the function parameter takes on object of type `A`. Thus the object in the function now is of the type `A` and it gets destroyed while returning from the function resulting in call output `~A(2)`.

The following two traces are from the destruction of the object `b` which is created in the `main()`, Since it is of the type of `B` destructors for base class `A` and derived class `B` both are called for it.

I am not sure if I missed out any obvious optimization that gcc might be performing in this case but for me the outputs look pretty much as expected.

Comment: Note that only modification I made was of adding an additional trace to `~B()` just for more clarity.

Comment: Thank you. But there is no answer on my issue where outputs are different :(

Comment: @DaddyM: Well you haven't provided the details asked by the users here about the compiler that you are using, Given that how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: FYI my post was edited 5 hours ago (added compiler version) while your comment was posted only 1 hour ago (at 10PM GMT+4). Please, re-read the initial post. I appreciate any help!

Comment: @DaddyM: FYI.The regular members(like me) answering Q's here, answer a lot of Q's everyday So do not expect them to re-visit and re-check each Q they answered for vital info that is expected to be there in the first place, Unless you explicitly write them a comment with the @ they wouldn't know & really wouldn't bother to check.I checked the behavior on msvc and it shows me the same behavior as mentioned in the Q.And I don't know the reason for it.Probably, looking in to the generated assembly code might help understand the reason.

Comment: Ok. I'll keep it in mind for the future. I suppose assembly will show us double copying and nothing more. In other words assembly will not explain us the reason.